# Express.js app timeout when getting data from S3 running in EKS pod

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

**Context**: My app gets an object from an AWS S3 bucket.

When I run the code on my machine it works, so the code actually seems right.

On the other hand, when I deploy the app to our AWS EKS cluster, it takes like 20min to resolve the request, and the response is actually a timeout error:

`TimeoutError: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.31.2.175:443`

I know the connection between my k8s pod and our S3 bucket is working because I can download the file manually within the pod terminal using `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/file .`

Process to request the file:

1. Access the app by the URL of my app in the k8s: `<appURL>/api/s3/files/index.js`
   1.1 The Bucket name is in an environment variable, while the filename is in the request params.

Code that runs when reaching that endpoint:

```
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import env from '@configs/env';
import logger from '@configs/logger';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

const { BUCKET } = env;
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-west-2' });

const AwsS3Controller = async (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => {
    logger.http(`AWS S3 Controller called.`);

    const { filename } = req.params;

    if (!filename) {
        next(new Error('Filename is required.'));
    }

    try {
        logger.info(`Fetching file: ${filename}`);
        const data = await s3Client.send(
            new GetObjectCommand({
                Bucket: BUCKET,
                Key: filename
            })
        );
        logger.info('File fetched.');

        if (!data.Body) {
            next(new Error('File not found.'));
        }

        const file = data.Body! as NodeJS.ReadableStream;
        logger.info(file);

        res.attachment(filename);
        res.type(data.ContentType!);
        file.pipe(res);
        logger.info('File sent.');
        // res.send(file);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

export default AwsS3Controller;
```

The `BUCKET` environment variable is correctly set, otherwise the package `ts-dotenv` would fail when starting the app.

I followed these code examples to create the app: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_s3_code_examples.html

PS.: As mentioned, the code seems to be working because it successfully retrieve the file when running locally.